# how refresh value of textfield when JFrame is closed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have created a program that reads a file and tally the values and print the totals to a text field every time I click a button(execute button), I attached this text field in a JFrame.

My code works well but my problem is every time I close the JFrame and click the button again the value is my JTextField is retained, and on my second click of the execute button the totals will multiply by two.  Can any one help me? I want to refresh the my JTextfield every time I close my JFrame. Here is the code I used.  Thanks!

```
      ArrayList<String>totalResult= newArrayList<String>();
      try
      {
        FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(AddressFile);
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(f1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
        String lines;

        while((lines = br1.readLIne())!=null)
        {
           if(line.length()!=0 && (lines.charAt(0)!='#'))
           {
              String[] employee = lines.split("\\s+");
              totalResult.add(employee[2]);
           }
        }
        for(String s : totalResult)
        {
           vacationLeave = Double.parseDouble(s);
           totalVacationLeave +=vacationLeave
        } 
        try
        {
          while(!loopVacationLeave)
          try
          {
             BigDecimal roundOff = new DigDecimal(totalVacationLeave).setScale(3, 
             RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;)
             totalVacationLeave = roundOff.doubleValue();

             if(SUMMARY_MONITORING_PERSONNEL.employeeVL7.getText()!=null)
               SUMMARY_MONITORING_PERSONNEL.employeeVL7.setText("" + 
                             totalVacationLeave);
               loopVacationLeave = true;
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           in1.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
             SUMMARY_MONITORING_PERSONNEL.employeeVL7.setText("No File");
           }
```

Comment: what is your `in1.close();` method?Show the whole code!

Comment: Do you create instance of JFrame class every time while trying to open Frame or create instance only one time and use this instance for every time. ? Please check this. Post [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing? show. `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` , `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` , `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` or `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` , If you are exiting or disposing off you can not do it.
IF you want to save the state of your frame so HIDE it, (When user click `X` button at top) it will only not visible to screen and any modification can be done and than you need SHOW it.

**OR**

you can do manually `frame.setVisible(true|false);`

[also see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#HIDE_ON_CLOSE)